# Why is the shading different on these cubes?

Tags: texturing, uv

Can someone explain why the shading is different on these cubes? Ideally, I want them all to have the same shading as the cube on the left.

[image]

Any help would be **HUGELY** appreciated

Comment: More information would be very helpful... Light source(s), render engine, maybe upload your .blend file http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/  etc.

Comment: What render engine are you using and what material setup did you apply? It may be a lighting problem, but it also looks like a smoothing or normal artifact, hard to tell without any valid information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i don't know if i got it right but you can use a Hemi lamp

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi Mohammad, that is exactly the effect I was looking for! Is there any chance I could have your .blend file because I've played around with mine too much now? I'll just edit the material and re-add the textures. Thanks for your comment!

Comment: I've sorted it now so don't worry, thanks again for your comment.

Comment: youre welcome,  well just in case  [<img src="http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=1126" />](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/1126/)   also you can turn on Ambient Occlusion in in the world options (if you like it )  its already on in the .blend file